# importxml for HTML tag without a class

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do an importxml on googlesheets, I'm trying to get the value within the first span tag "**$2,760,771,621 USD**" in the following code

```
<ul class="cmc-details-panel-stats k1ayrc-0 gkPvKy">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>$2,760,771,621 USD</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>$394,018,520 USD</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried

> =IMPORTXML("website.com","//ul[@class='cmc-details-panel-stats']")

and get a **#N/A**

How can this be done?

Comment: I think that your HTML is incomplete like `</div><`. If this is the actual HTML, I think that the values cannot be directly retrieved with the xpath. How about this?

Comment: the extra < is a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for quickly updating it. Although I think that in this case, it might be required to test using the URL, if you want to retrieve `$2,760,771,621 USD` the sample HTML in your question, how about this xpath? `//ul[contains(@class,'cmc-details-panel-stats')]/li[1]//span` But, if this was not the direct solution, can you provide the URL for testing?

Comment: the url is https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cardano/ I'm trying to get the value for market cap in usd

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the URL. In that case, please test this formula `=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cardano/","//ul[contains(@class,'cmc-details-panel-stats')]/li[1]//span[1]")`

Comment: I posted the modified formula including the result image as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By your provided information, I could think of the solution. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would like to propose the xpath of `//ul[contains(@class,'cmc-details-panel-stats')]/li[1]//span[1]`.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//ul[contains(@class,'cmc-details-panel-stats')]/li[1]//span[1]")
```

- In this formula, the URL of `https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cardano/` is put in the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In this case, I thought that the following sample HTML might be suitable for thinking the solution as the sample HTML.

  ```
    <ul class="cmc-details-panel-stats k1ayrc-0 gkPvKy">
        <li>
            <div>
                <span>$2,760,771,621 USD</span><span>###</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <span>$394,018,520 USD</span><span>###</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  ```

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)